# Add Bot in Orchard Core

Tags: c#, routes, .net-core, botframework, orchardcms

I am trying to add a Bot using Microsoft Bot Framework in an Orchard Core CMS application. I am relatively new to Orchard Core, I have setup a new project using Orchard Core templates.

**Problem Context / Scenario:**

- I want to add a Bot into my site using Orchard Core
- I have created a custom module using the Orchard Core template and am able to add ApiController to handle a specific route
- I'm trying to build a Bot using Microsoft Bot Framework SDK V4
- I'm trying to add my Bot using `services.AddBot<MyBot>`. I do not receive any error during build as well as run.

  - By default using `services.AddBot<MyBot>()` registers for a URL `/api/messages` I tried this endpoint and unable to access my Bot
  - I understand that the Orchard Core handles the routing and may not be aware of this URL

**Here are my problems:**
- Is there a way to let Orchard Core know about this route?
- Eventually I want to be able to enable this module under multiple tenants in my Orchard Core CMS site

Comment: I assume you are using the UseBotFramework extension method in your Startup class Configure method? Looks like this maps the endpoint handlers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.integration.aspnet.core.applicationbuilderextensions.usebotframework?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm going to take an educated guess that you are running into a problem with the order of registration of handlers with the `IApplicationBuilder` during startup. If you're not aware, the order that you map things on the app builder *really* matters.

Because you have an existing code base I'm going to guess that when you added the bot you added the `.UseBotFramework()` call at the end. Since `UseBotFramework()` will register your bot under `/api/messages` by default, there's a good chance existing MVC routes that you already had mapped are "swallowing" the requests intended to go to the bot. You have two choices to remedy this:

1. Move the `.UseBotFramework()` so that it is before any other route mapping so that it will have first dibs on handling the incoming request.
2. Change the route that the bot will listen on so that it doesn't conflict with your API controller route. This is done during the `AddBot<YourBot>(…)` call like so:

```cs
services.AddBot<YourBot>(options => 
{
    options.Paths.BasePath = "bots";
});
```

And this will cause the path to become `/bots/messages` instead. You can also change the `/messages` if you wanted via `options.Paths.MessagesPath`.

Answer (score 0):

With OrchardCore you can plug into the route builder by overriding a Configure Method in the StartupBase. I assume you're adding services.AddBot in a custom Startup class that already inherits from StartupBase?

Have a look at the other override in StartupBase

```
public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IRouteBuilder routes, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    routes.MapAreaRoute(
        name: "a-route-name",
        areaName: "area-name",
        template: "api/messages",
        defaults: new { controller = "Bot", action = "Index" }
    );
}
```

You will need to figure out the correct route that UseBotFramework uses